# /proc/cpuinfo for Xeon E3 processor

Tags: cpu, cpu-cores

I have Intel XEON E3-1230 with a single socket configuration, and according to http://ark.intel.com/products/52271/Intel-Xeon-Processor-E3-1230-8M-Cache-3_20-GHz it has at most 4 cores, however on my Fedora 20 "cat /proc/cpuinfo" reports 8 processor lines, ie:

```
% cat /proc/cpuinfo |grep ^processor
processor       : 0
processor       : 1
processor       : 2
processor       : 3
processor       : 4
processor       : 5
processor       : 6
processor       : 7
```

And under every 'processor' it reports 4 cpu cores. What does the number of processors in cpuinfo output mean?

Answer (score 0):

Linux reports the number of threads. Nowadays, most processors have 2 threads per core, so `4 cores * 2 threads / core = 8 threads`. This means you can have at most 8 processes running at the same time (in realtime).